# Cant persist a Hashset in hibernate

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, spring-mvc

I am having trouble in saving a Hashset in hibernate. I am trying to save more than one entries but it is only saving the first item it gets. I am looping through and adding new element to set in every iteration but in the end its size is always 1. After execution, in database table, a new priceList is created but only one entry is created in price table (It should create 5). More info in images.

**PriceList.java**

```
@Id @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;
    public void setId(int id){
        this.id = id;
    }
    public Integer getId(){
        return this.id;
    }

    @Column(name = "name")
    @NotBlank( message = "Name is required" )
    private String name;
    public void setName(String name){
        this.name = name;
    }
    public String getName(){
        return this.name;
    }

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "priceList", fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JsonIgnore
    private Set<Price> prices = new HashSet<Price>();
    public void setPrices(Set<Price> prices)
    {
        this.prices.addAll(prices);
    }
    public Set<Price> getPrices()
    {   return this.prices; }
```

**Price.java**

```
@Id @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;
    public void setId(int id){
        this.id = id;
    }
    public Integer getId(){
        return this.id;
    }

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "product_id",referencedColumnName = "id")
    @JsonSerialize(using = ProductSerializer.class)
    private Product product;
    public void setProduct(Product product){
        this.product = product;
    }
    public Product getProduct(){
        return this.product;
    }

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "price_list_id",referencedColumnName = "id",updatable = true,insertable = true)
    private PriceList priceList;
    public void setPriceList(PriceList priceList){
        this.priceList = priceList;
    }
    public PriceList getPriceList(){
        return this.priceList;
    }

    @Column(name = "price")
    private float price;
    public void setPrice(float price){
        this.price = price;
    }
    public float getPrice(){
        return this.price;
    }

    @Column(name = "discount")
    private float discount;
    public void setDiscount(float discount){
        this.discount = discount;
    }
    public float getDiscount(){
        return this.discount;
    }
```

In My Controller i am doing this

**Controller**

```
PriceList defaultPriceList = priceListService.findDefaultPriceList();
                    List<Price> defaultPriceListPrices = pricesService.findPricesByPriceList(defaultPriceList);
                    Set<Price> newPrices = new HashSet<Price>();

                    System.out.println(defaultPriceListPrices.size());
                    for (Price p : defaultPriceListPrices)
                    {
                        Price myPrice = new Price();
                        myPrice.setPrice(p.getPrice());
                        myPrice.setDiscount(p.getDiscount());
                        myPrice.setProduct(p.getProduct());
                        myPrice.setPriceList(p.getPriceList());

                        newPrices.add(myPrice);

                        System.out.println("product id" + myPrice.getProduct().getId());
                        System.out.println("price list id" + myPrice.getPriceList().getId());
                        System.out.println("price" + myPrice.getPrice());
                        System.out.println("discount" + myPrice.getDiscount());
                        System.out.println();

                    }
                    System.out.println("new prices size" + newPrices.size());

                    priceList.setPrices(newPrices);
                  priceListService.save(priceList);
```

I am currently getting this output on console

[image]

**Before Execution**

[image]

[image]

**After Execution**

[image]

[image]

**UPDATE**

**Price.java**

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object object) {
    if (object instanceof Price) {
        Price price = (Price) object;
        return
                price.getId() == this.getId() && price.getPriceList().getId() == this.getPriceList().getId();
    }
    return true;
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    return new HashCodeBuilder(17,37)
            .append(id)
            .toHashCode();
}
```

Comment: This smells like a problem of an improperly implemented hashCode() method. Does the Price class have one?

Comment: No it does not. Class code is complete minus the import statements. I think it needs some fixing in the controller code.

Comment: I would still try implementing (or letting your IDE generate) a hashcode and equals method. A Set does not allow duplicate entries and that is what I see happening in the code VS the log output. You're adding 5 prices to the set, and 4 of them don't actually end up in there.

Comment: Dear Gimby, I am really sorry. Price class had those methods. I have attached them in the update please review. Thanks

Comment: So if all the new Price objects have no id, which they don't because you're not setting it, they are all going to be duplicates of each other.

Comment: Shouldn't they be autogenerated by hibernate?

Comment: That happens on save, not when you're creating the objects.

Comment: So i should save them in the loop?

Comment: Your hashcode() and equals() method are not consistent. I think that the id should be enough to identify a `Price` instance.Implementing both methods by using only the id.

Comment: So how should they be changed?

Comment: Just use the id of Price. Don't refer to  `price.getPriceList().getId()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is with your `hashCode` implementation on `Price`.

Implementations of both `equals` and `hashCode` often wrong because they base their equality and hash calculation solely off the value of the entity's `ID` only.  In cases of newly created instances where the `ID` is a `@GeneratedValue` result, this won't work.

In your case, everytime you add a new `Price` instance to your `Set<>`, the same `hashCode` value is calculated because each new instance has a null `ID`, so they keep getting replaced.

Adjust your `equals` and `hashCode` implementations:

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object object) {
  if ( object == this ) {
    return true; // instance equality
  }
  if ( object == null || object.getClass() != getClass() ) {
    return false; 
  }
  final Price other = Price.class.cast( object );
  if ( getId() == null && other.getId() == null ) {
    // perform equality check against all non-id attributes
  }
  else {
    // perform equality check only on id
  }
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
  final HashCodeBuilder hcb = new HashCodeBuilder( 17, 37 );
  if ( id == null ) {
     hcb.append( price );
     hcb.append( discount );
     // other fields
  }
  else {
    // only identity basis
    hcb.append( id );
  }
  return hcb.toHashCode();
}
```

This makes sure that when comparing two non-persisted objects of a `Price`, their comparison/hash is based on the non-identity attributes.  Once persisted, the methods will base their comparison/hash against only the identity value, allowing for two instances where one have been modified and the other hasn't to equate to the same.

Answer (score 1):

Your code seem to make a copy in a some way a set of existing `Price` instances in a new `PriceList` instance and as last step it persists these new data (the new `PriceList` and the new `Price` instances).

If I am right, look closely at the `price_list_id` column value recorded in your `Price` table after inserting.
You don't use as fk the new `price_list_id` (36) but you still use the `price_list_id` (25) used by the previous set of prices.

The problem is in the loop where you write 
  `myPrice.setPriceList(p.getPriceList());` instead of referencing `priceList`, the variable referencing the new `PriceList` instance you are creating and you are using to set the `prices` Set before persisting the `PriceList` instance :

```
priceList.setPrices(newPrices);
priceListService.save(priceList);
```

I think that replacing `myPrice.setPriceList(p.getPriceList());` by `myPrice.setPriceList(priceList);` should solve your problem.

Comment: Sorry that was a typing mistake. I adjusted the code as you suggested but still the same result (only 1 record insrted). Only the price_list_id column now has the id of newly created.